# How to update EF Core Tools to the latest version

Tags: entity-framework-core

I get the following warning:

> The EF Core tools version '3.0.0-preview8.19405.11' is older than that
>   of the runtime '3.1.0'. Update the tools for the latest features and
>   bug fixes.

Any idea what I need to run to update EF Core Tools?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

At the command line, use:

```
dotnet tool update --global dotnet-ef --version 3.1.0
```

Comment: I had to restart VS after this to stop getting the error

Answer (score 1):

## To Solve This Issue You May Follow One Of The Following Techniques:

---

- **Technique 1:**  Using Package Manager Console(Especially for Microsoft Visual Studio user) 
   **PM**> `Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools -Version 3.1.0`
- **Technique 2:** Using **.NET CLI** 
   > `dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools --version 3.1.0`
- **Technique 3:**  Using Package Reference

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="3.1.0">
  <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
  <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers</IncludeAssets>
</PackageReference>
```

- **Technique 4:** Using **Packet CLI** 
   > `paket add Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools --version 3.1.0`

> **Remember:** For this version to use you need *NuGet 3.6 or higher.* 
> **Reference Link:** ***https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools/3.1.0***